# Why ng serve is showing multiple times in process monitor

Tags: angular, ubuntu, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I am developing few applications using .net core and angular in Ubuntu OS.
Due to drastic performance loss on my laptop I checked the current process in execution using Htop.

[image]

Its showing lot of instances of `ng serve`.
Is this some error or expected behavior of angular?

I am using `VS Code` and `Tilix terminal emulator` in `Ubuntu 20.04` machine with `4 GB of RAM`.

Comment: any updates on this one? I also have this kind of behaviour

Comment: Not yet. Still facing this. I have added some more RAM to avoid machine getting stuck. @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer

Comment: Has any angular developers aware of this or any issue has been raised about this one?

Comment: Posted the same in code project also. Lets see. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5279506/Why-ng-serve-is-showing-multiple-times-in-process

Comment: i have asked it in the official discord and it seems like it's nodejs specific. Here's the offical angular discord if you want to ask something about it.
https://discord.com/invite/byeaHUj